How to inject @Configuration to be seen in a JPA @Entity
src/main/resources/application.properties
cdn.url = http://foo.mycompany.com
cdn.prefix = reports

CDN configuration
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cdn")
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CDNConfig {
    private String url;
    private String prefix;
}

CDN JPA Entity. I would like to inject the values of CDNConfig which is getting populated on load into JPA Entity, which I am not able to do in a proper fashion. How can I bring in the values from CDNConfig into CDN.java so that I can use the CDN config values?
I tried representing CDNConfig as a Component, it didn't work.
I tried @Autowired of CDNConfig in JPA entity, it didn't work either.
@Slf4j
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@Table(name = "cdn")
public class CDN {

    @Transient
    private CDNConfig cdnConfig; 

}


see https://onecompiler.com/posts/3uy2eu6fh/how-to-use-spring-bean-reference-in-static-methods how to gain static access to Spring Beans. This could be a way to access the Configuration from the entity...

or use JPA Lifecycle events: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events

Why? Why do you need this to be part of the entity? It is transient anyway so I don't see the benefit (in adding all the complexity).

I meant, I need to reuse the configuration while performing some calculation in the Entity. So just need a mechanism to use Configuration

Problem
You need to inject CDNConfig to CDN
Solution
CDN is not a bean => do not keeps at Spring container => @Autowired not works. Also constructor injection will not works properly, method-based too.
You need pass CDNConfig via constructor:
...
public class CDN {

  // ...

  @Transient
  private CDNConfig cdnConfig;

  public CDN(CDNConfig cdnConfig) {
    this.url = cdnConfig.getUrl();
  }

  // ...
}

And in code where you create a new CDN you need extract CDNConfig and pass it to constructor:
...
CDNConfig cdnConfig = applicationContext.getBean(CDNConfig.class);
CDN cdn = new CDN(cdnConfig);
...

It is not best solution and do a code in another way, but it will works if you need 

In such case you can also do private CDNConfig cdnConfig as final field:
private final CDNConfig cdnConfig; 


CDN is a JPA Entity, so not sure if it would work taking the argument in the constructor. We did use private final CDNConfig cdnConfig, but the values were still empty

You cannot use constructor injection as JPA ignores it.

@M.Deinum Couldn't at least for new created entities this solution work, given a non-args constructor is also provided for the JPA provider? Although I think this wouldn't be an elegant solution. Anyhow, the questioner didn't specify when and how to use CDNConfig, meaning for new entities or db pulled ones, so this would be just a possibility in case.

And fail miserably when retrieving from the database.

There is no info about how that entity will process further. Also there is used @Transient annotation, that ignore field for JPA. So it is works.

The final Transient CDNConfig cdnConfig; solution doesn't work either
